# Can django prefetch related work with 3 lookups?

Tags: python, django

I want to prefetch 3 tables plus the initial table. Here are model examples of the project i am working on

```
class ExampleOne(models.Model):
      name = models.Charfield()
      option = models.BooleanField()
      money = MoneyField()
      that_date = models.DateTimeField()

class ExampleTwo(models.Model):
      word = models.Charfield()
      example_one = models.ManyToManyField(ExampleOne)
      number = models.IntegerField()

class ExampleThree(models.Model):
      number = models.IntegerField()
      example_two = models.ForeignKey(ExampleTwo)
      this_date = models.DateTimeField()

      @property
      def get_calculation_one(self):
          if self.example_two.example_one.exists():
              for example1 in self.example_two.example_one.all():
                  if example1.option is not None:
                      if self.this_date >= example1.that_date):
                           return self.number * example1.money.amount
                  else:
                       if self.this_date >= datetime.today()):
                           return self.number * example1.money.amount   
         else:
             return 0

class ExampleFour(models.Model):
      date = models.DateField()
      example_three = models.ManyToManyField(ExampleThree)

      @property
      def get_calculation_two(self):
          cost = 0
          if self.example_three.exists():
               for example3 in self.example_three.all():
                    cost += example3.get_calculation_one
               return cost
          return cost
```

Now I want to know if it is possible to retrieve data from all these models with as little hits to the database as possible because when I try to retrieve data it takes over one minute to retrieve the data and send it to the frontend

The calculation might be making many database hits in order to get the data and calculate and I think that is why it is taking more than a minute to retrieve the data

my view looks like this

```
        qs = ExampleFour.objects.prefetch_related(
             Prefetch('example_three__example_two__example_one')
        ).filter(...)
```

Is there a way to use prefetch to make the retrieval faster or is there another suggestion on I can rewrite my code in order to avoid this long retrieval time?

Note I am still new to Django

I am also using DRF so here are how the serializers look

```
 class ExampleOneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

      class Meta:
           model = ExampleOne
           fields = (
                    "name",
                    "option",
                    "money",
                    "that_date",
                     )

   
class ExampleTwoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      
      example_1_value = serializers.SerializerMethodField()            

      class Meta:
           model = ExampleOne
           fields = (
                    "word",
                    "example_one",
                    "number",
                     )
           read_only_fields =(
                    "example_1_value",
                    )

      def get_example_1_value(self, obj):
         return ExampleOneSerializer(obj.example_one.latest('that_date')
                                     ).data

class ExampleThreeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

      example_2_data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
      get_calculation_one = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

      class Meta:
           model = ExampleOne
           fields = (
                    "number", 
                    "example_two",
                    "this_date",
                    "example_2_data",
                    "get_calculation_one",
                    )
           read_only_fields =(
                    "example_2_data",
                    "get_calculation_one",
                    )
   
     def get_example_2_data(self, obj):
         return ExampleTwoSerializer(obj.example_two).data

class ExampleFourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      
      example_3_data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
      get_calculation_two = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

      class Meta:
           model = ExampleOne
           fields = (
                    "date",
                    "example_three",
                    "example_3_data",
                    "get_calculation_two",
                     )
           read_only_fields =(
                    "example_3_data",
                    "get_calculation_two",
                    )
      
     def get_example_3_data(self, obj):
         return ExampleThreeSerializer(obj.example_three.all(), 
                                         many=True).data
```

I wonder if would prefetch work on the serializer side or would it be redundant

Comment: So far your prefetch looks ok. You might have to share how you use `qs` and/or your calculations, just to check if you unintentionally cancelled the prefetch in those

Comment: My qs is sent as a response to the frontend. I don't use it for anything else

Comment: From your latest edit, the prefetch can be cancelled with `obj.example_one.latest('that_date')` since it implies a new query